# Angular directive template missing closing tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create a directive in angularjs which will generate few lines of html depending on the tag and text passed in vie attributes. The directive usage looks like this -

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <my-field my-text="sample text" my-tag="h1"></my-field>
</div>
```

My directive goes like this -

```
.directive('myField', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace : false,
        scope : {
            myText : '@',
            myTag : '@',
        },
        template : '<{{myTag}}> {{myText}} </{{myTag}}>',
    }
})
```

The result I get is like this -

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1> sample text
</div>
```

The closing `</h1>` is missing. I have have been struggling with it for hours now but could not get it fixed.

Here is the [Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mcJ4P/)

Comment: i added `console.log(element)` to the link function and get: `&lt;h1&gt; sample text <!--{{mytag}}-->` as the innerHtml.  so angular is commenting out the closing `mytag`?

Comment: looks like, after registering the opening mytag(h1) its not able to accept a closing tag which is not h1(mytag). So I think angular is not table to match the opening mytag and closing mytag, thats why its ignoring the closing mytag.. I  don't know whats the solution in this case!

Comment: Angular may be refusing to render your interpolated closing tag for security reasons. Though you're not using `ng-bind-html`, it still might be worthwhile reading about [Strict Contextual Escaping](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce).

Comment: The `compile` function in a directive is typically the place that turns curly braces into other things, but that's a bit more advanced. You don't have `compile`, `link`, or even `controller` defined, which makes this directive almost meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a weird quirky thing. For some reason it does not want to evaluate the mytag value twice, so here is a way to get around it. Using the link function and $compile, you can fix it and it works as intended.

```
link: function(scope, elem) {
    var tag = scope.mytag;
    var newelem = angular.element("<"+tag+"> {{mytext}}</ "+tag+">");
    var compiled = $compile(newelem)(scope);
    elem.append(compiled);
}
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXwmJ/)

Comment: Hi Zack, I know this is an altenate way. I am trying to avoid this method because I have multiple line html to generate and they will have a number of ng- directives. Template way is easy as it takes care of sanitization and compiling etc itself. Just for info, it evaluate the mytag twice. if you just remove '/', it evaluated it well. Just that its not able to take it as the closing tag for the previously opened tag. Thanks for the help though :-)

Answer (score 0):

might be too verbose, yet works.
pass open and close tags as attributes constructed with parenthesis

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('myField', function(){
 return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace : false,
    scope : {
        myText : '@',
        openTag : '@',
        closeTag: '@'
    },
    template : '{{openTag}} {{myText}} {{closeTag}}',
 }
})


<div class="wrapper">
  <my-field my-text="sample text" open-tag="<h1>" close-tag="</h1>"></my-field>
</div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N5FLN/1/